# How to specify type of key, value pair in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to print out a dictionary in the following format. I want to do this because I need to print out a bar graph in D3 using the JSON format.

```
[
  {
    "Month": "January",
    "Freq": 52928
  },
  {
    "Month": "March",
    "Freq": 51444
  },
  {
    "Month": "April",
    "Freq": 51209
  },
  {
    "Month": "May",
    "Freq": 53394
  },
  {
    "Month": "June",
    "Freq": 53662
  },
  {
    "Month": "July",
    "Freq": 58696
  },
  {
    "Month": "August",
    "Freq": 58072
  },
  {
    "Month": "December",
    "Freq": 55187
  },
  {
    "Month": "November",
    "Freq": 50016
  },
  {
    "Month": "February",
    "Freq": 46079
  },
  {
    "Month": "October",
    "Freq": 53650
  },
  {
    "Month": "September",
    "Freq": 54117
  }
]
```

Currently, I have it like [`{'Wyoming': 630, 'Alaska': 1617}]`.  How do I do turn it into the above format? I have added it to a list because I also need the dictionary in an array.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('Wyoming.xlsx')
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
statesDict1 = dict()

allStates = df["State"]
for key in allStates:
    if key in statesDict1:
        statesDict1[key] += 1
    else:
        s = {key:1}
        statesDict1.update(s)

#print(statesDict)
statesDict = list()
statesDict.append(statesDict1)
# file = open("MurderRateState.js", "w+")
# file.write(json.dumps(statesDict))
# file.close()
print(statesDict)
```

[image: Dataset]

Comment: That gives me the error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: I don't see where you expect  to find date information.

Comment: You will need to traverse your stateDict1 and build statesDict.

Comment: Can you show what the xlsx file looks like?

Comment: What is the relationship between the title, the first line of your question, what  you _currently_ have, and your code? Please, clarify the structure and content of the `xlsx` file and the result you want to get.

Comment: It means that how I do print the type of the key and value in the dictionary. All I'm trying to do is print out the dictionary so that I am able to build a bar graph in D3 from the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections
import json

class OrderedCounter(collections.Counter, collections.OrderedDict):
    """Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered."""
    pass

month_frequencies = OrderedCounter(df['Month']).items()

output_dicts = [{'Month': m, 'Freq': f} for m, f in month_frequencies]
print(json.dumps(output_dicts))
```

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#json.dumps)

Comment: How would I sort by the month?  It appears as though the order of the keys does not maintain the same order as presented in the excel file.

Comment: @treatyoself There's a handy [`OrderedCounter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) recipe that does just that. Just use `items()` instead of `most_common()` to get back the months in the order they're found.

Comment: How would the syntax look?